# Functors vs. std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-bind

Sometimes I tend to write functors, not for the sake of maintaining state between function calls, but because I want to capture some arguments that are shared between function calls. As an example:

```
class SuperComplexAlgorithm
{
    public:
        SuperComplexAlgorithm( unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int z )
            : x_( x ), y_( y ), z_( z )
        {}

        unsigned int operator()( unsigned int arg ) const /* yes, const! */
        {
            return x_ * arg * arg + y_ * arg + z_;
        }

    private:
        // Lots of parameters are stored as member variables.
        unsigned int x_, y_, z_;
};

// At the call site:
SuperComplexAlgorithm a( 3, 4, 5 );
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    do_stuff_with( a ); // or whatever
```

Compared to

```
unsigned int superComplexAlgorithm( unsigned int x, unsigned int y,
                                    unsigned int z, unsigned int arg )
{
    return x * arg * arg + y * arg + z;
}

// At the call site:
auto a = std::bind( superComplexAlgorithm, 3, 4, 5, std::placeholders::_1 );
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    do_stuff_with( a );
```

the first solution has a lot of drawbacks, in my opinion:

- Documentation of what `x`, `y`, `z` do is split at different places (constructor, class definition, `operator()`).
- Lots of boiler-plate code.
- Less flexible. What if I want to capture a different sub-set of parameters?

Yes, I just realized how useful `boost::bind` or `std::bind` can be. Now for my question before I start using this in a lot of my code: Is there any situation where I should consider using a hand-written stateless functor over binding arguments in a plain function?

Comment: above all you should consider lambdas

Comment: @stijn: I don't want to define `superComplexAlgorithm` at the call site, because it is super complex, is used in many places, needs testing and documentation, etc.. I can't see how lambdas can be helpful in this situation, although I use them a lot in other situations.

Comment: @MarkusMayr, you can replace `std::bind` with a lambda. Instead of `std::bind( superComplexAlgorithm, 3, 4, 5, std::placeholders::_1 )`, you write `[](int x) { return superComplexAlgorithm(3, 4, 5, x); }`.

Comment: @avakar: Yes, that is doing exactly the same as `std::bind`, except that `std::bind` makes clear what my intentions were and the lambda expression does not (at least not at first glance). Even if you prefer lambdas in this case: Can you think of any situation where I should prefer a hand-written functor over one created with a lambda expression or `std::bind`?

Comment: Since lambdas became available to me, I haven't used `bind` or overloaded `operator()` even once. So no, I can't imagine such a situation :) Put the code into the lambda or write a function and call it from the lambda.

Comment: It's handy if you want to put more complex logic into `SuperComplexAlgorithm`.  It allows you to easily add new methods that can handle some of the details without passing the arguments around and without introducing the names into a larger scope.

Comment: I'd like to note that the "official" name of this pattern is [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I'm not so sure it is.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Currying is technically the single-argument function chain with binding, not all partial-binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lambda solution would be the idomatic C++11 way:

```
auto a = [&]( int x ){ return superComplexAlgorithm( 3, 4, 5, x ); };
for( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
  do_stuff_with( a );
```

The advantage of using a hand written functor is that you can:

1. Move arguments into the capture, or transform them (you can do that with lambda in C++1y, but not yet -- this is also possible with `bind`)
2. It has a non-anonymous type (so you can talk about the type without using `auto`) -- the same is true of `bind`, but it also has a non-anonymous *meaningful* type you can get at without `decltype`ing the entire expression!  C++1y again makes this better for `bind`/lambda.
3. You can do perfect forwarding of the remaining arguments (you might be able to do this in C++1y with a lambda, and `bind` does this)
4. You can mess around with how the captured data is stored (in a pointer? a smart pointer?) without messing up the code where you create the instance.

You can also do some extremely powerful things with hand written functors that are impossible to do with `bind` and lambdas, like wrap an overload set of multiple functions into one object (that may or may not share a name), but that kind of corner case isn't going to show up often.

Comment: Why do you have a capture clause in your lambda? You shouldn't use captures unless you actually need to capture something.

Comment: Why capture by reference if there is no capture at all?

Comment: @sebastianredl It makes it similar to bind: usually the values you bind are not compile time constants, or you would not bother with `bind` or a lambda: a plain old function would do.  And the runtime cost is zero if I am wrong, so I included it.

Comment: If you want to emulate `bind`, use a copy capture.

Comment: +1 @SebastianRedl: also, beware if you are *capturing* members

Comment: You are *never* capturing members. In C++11, you can only capture objects with automatic storage duration: locals and function parameters. If you think you are capturing members, you are in fact implicitly capturing `this`. (I also dislike capture defaults, but that's really a style issue - they exceed my personal threshold for implicit behavior.)

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any situation where I should consider using a hand-written stateless functor over binding arguments in a plain function?

From the comments:

> I don't want to define superComplexAlgorithm at the call site, because it is super complex, is used in many places, needs testing and documentation, etc..

If the implementation of `superComplexAlgorithm` requires a bunch of code and you end up splitting it into different functions that take a large amount of arguments, then you might be better off with a class that provides the shared state across the internal implementation functions. Other that that corner case, the behavior of `std::bind` would be equivalent to the functor you provided in the question.

Some notes, since you mention `boost::bind` and `std::bind` as alternatives. You might want to test what your implementation does. For example, with boost 1.35 (ancient) the `bind` operation would make 4 copies of each argument, VS2010 would make 7 copies in `std::bind` although `std::bind` in gcc 4.7 did only 1. If the arguments are small that won't make up to a high cost, but if you are doing the operation or your objects are expensive to copy... just measure.

Regarding the lambda, if performance is an issue, also measure how it behaves. It should make a single copy. If performance is not an issue, then a lambda is far less explicit on what is being captured (the user needs to read the implementation of the lambda to figure that out), and even looking at the code it might not be that obvious.